# ¿Hay alguna manera de restringir el acceso a alguna ruta de Laravel si el usuario ya se autenticó/inició sesión?

Tags: php, laravel

estoy trabajando con un proyecto de laravel y quiero que el usuario no tenga acceso a una ruta en específico si ya inició sesión. Algo similar con las rutas a las que se requiere que se haya autenticado, pero en mi caso lo contrario.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 2):

en el archivo routes/web.php

puede añadir una condición si esta autenticado lo puede redireccionar

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    if (\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::check()) {

        return redirect('/home');
    } else {
        return view('auth/login');
    }
});
```

si necesita restringir los acceso de algunos usuario puede utilizar la siguiente funcion

```
  Route::get("home", function () {
        if (Auth::user()->id == 1 || Auth::user()->id == 24 || Auth::user()->id == 19) {
            return redirect('/Gerencia_OYM');
        }
        return View::make("home");
    })->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: Miil gracias amigo!!

Comment: si la respuesta  le funciono favor votar  en la fecha haca arriba